# How to properly apply PrePersist like logic using jpa/spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I have a very simple use case for the following model

```
@Entity
@Table(name='Foo')
class Foo {
    @Id
    String id = UUID.randomUUID()    
    String bar
    Date foo_updated
}
```

I'd like to set the foo_updated value to new Date() when I see the incoming json payload has a value for "bar" (ie- this is a new value included in the POST/ a part of the PATCH update / included and proven to be different in a PUT)

I was hoping to simply apply the @PrePersist annotation on this model and add a simple conditional asking if "bar" was valid ...but quickly realized I wouldn't know if the value was "different" from what was in the db already (for the PATCH/PUT scenario).

I'm starting down the road of "add my own RestController" and apply this logic on the way in using the spring 4 ResponseEntity approach but ... I feel this might end up being a lot more work/more code to maintain.

As I'm new to spring-boot/spring-mvc/jpa I'm curious what other options I have and what the preferred approach would be for this seemingly "simple" requirement

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this approach recently which involves recording the previous state on load. You now have access to the previous state after the new values are bound.

```
@Entity
@Table(name='Foo')
class Foo {
    @Id
    String id = UUID.randomUUID()    
    String bar
    Date foo_updated

    @Transient
    private Foo previousState;

    @PostLoad
    private void setPreviousState(){
        previousState = new Foo();
        //copy the fields
    }

}
```

However in your case can't you just do:

```
@Entity
@Table(name='Foo')
class Foo {
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID()    
    private String bar
    private Date lastUpdated;

    public void setBar(String bar){
        if(! this.bar.equals(bar){
            lastUpdated = new Date();
        }
    }
}
```