# How to find which fields has been changed during @EntityListeners call

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitylisteners

Let's assume I have this class :

```
@EntityListeners({MyListener.class})
class MyClass {
  String name;
  String surname;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name; 
  }

  public String getSurname() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setSurname(String name) {
    this.name = name; 
  }
}
```

MyListener class will look this :

```
public class MyListener {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyListener.class.getName());

    public MyListener() {

    }

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    @PostRemove
    public void onPostPersist(MyClass object) {
        log.fine("Firing changed entity event");
    }
}
```

onPostPersist() method in MyListener class will gets called on change of MyClass instance field.

**Is it possible to find that this method has been called because of particular fields changes ?**

Eg:
*If I changed name field alone,I should be able to find name field has been changed in last persist.*

One way to check to by comparing with audit.

I would like to know alter approach if available.

Thanks

Comment: One approach is to store a reference to a copy of the entity using a @PostLoad listener. You can then compare against this on update. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26535005/1356423

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing makes sense only for update events. You can register an [interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html) and listen for the changes in the overridden `onFlushDirty` method:

```
onFlushDirty(Object entity,
             Serializable id,
             Object[] currentState,
             Object[] previousState,
             String[] propertyNames,
             Type[] types)
```

Here you have arrays of previous and current states and an array of properties, so you can easily find out what's changed.